# How to handle "CORS" issue while using office management API in Sharepoint addin

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I have used office management api for fetching of audit log in Sharepoint Addin but i am getting "CORS" issue.

API Name:- Office Management API
API URL:- https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/tenant-id/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint

I has followed all the step mention in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-apis-overview)

How can i Handle CORS issue?